# Jquery code works in firefox but not IE

Tags: jquery

I have the following event binded to many hyperlinks with the class "riskInformationButton". It works fine in firefox but not in IE.

```
$(".riskInformationButton").bind("click", function(e){ 

    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation( );  
    else e.cancelBubble = true;

    var toggler = $(this).parent().parent().next();         
    while(!toggler.hasClass("spacerRow")){                
        toggler = toggler.toggleClass("hidden").toggleClass("visible").next();         
    }
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance,

Shawn

Comment: Is there any error occurring?

Comment: What do your anchor tags look like?
As an aside, why not make it $("a.riskInformationButton")? I don't know if that affects execution speed, but personally I like to be as explicit as possible in my jquery query strings.

Comment: - there are no errors.

- anchor tags are just normal anchors.. <a id="idName" class="riskInofrmationButton">linkText</a>"

Answer (score 4):

You said you are binding to hypelinks. 
You should **return false** on the callback or call **e.preventDefault()**.

It is ok to use bind but you may want to use click instead:

```
$("riskInformationButton").click(function(e) {
     // your code
});
```

Comment: What's the difference in bind and click?
and returning false, or using e.preventDefault() didn't work.

where should e.preventDefault() be called?

Comment: e.preventDefault() can be called anywhere, you may call it on the beginning of the callback function.

Comment: Click is a shorthand for the bind("click") it won't make a difference. I think click is cleaner.