# jQuery toggleClass issue in IE

Tags: jquery

The following jQuery code works fine in FireFox but not in IE.

The loop executes the expected number of times(verified by counting alerts) but the hidden classes do not become visible.

```
 $("a.riskInformationButton").bind("click", function(e){ 
     var toggler = $(this).parent().parent().next();         
     while(!toggler.hasClass("spacerRow")){   
        alert("Hey!");             
        toggler = toggler.toggleClass("hidden").toggleClass("visible").next();         
    }
});
```

Any assistance with this issue would be much appreciated

Thanks,

Shawn

Comment: can you explain what you are trying to do in this line - `toggler = toggler.toggleClass("hidden").toggleClass("visible").next(); ?

Comment: to toggle between showing and hiding, you don't need to use toggleClass. Use toggle() - http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/toggle

Comment: You should improve your another question. Don't make the same question again. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404932/jquery-code-works-in-firefox-but-not-ie/

Answer (score 2):

Are they table rows?  jQuery has a [bug about table-rows and toggle in IE8](http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/4661).  Here's a [workaround](http://www.code-styling.de/english/jquery-132-causes-problems-at-ie-8).